# matlab gui with reset function

Tags: matlab

I'm making a simple game using a matlab gui.

The game involves multiple stages. (Used multiple panels and visible options) I want to add the reset function and the terminate function(exit) of the game.
They'll be activated by certain pushbuttons.
I hope when I press the reset button, the game returns to first stage(panel1) as if I first started a main gui function. (main_Openingfcn)

Also I hope terminate button to close whole gui functions.
Please let me know how to deal with it.

Comment: Please add your code to determine the best approach for you.

Comment: Thank you for your reformatting. I don't know how long I have to fill out the code since the code I wrote is rather long. I wonder if you have a function to shut down the gui interface or return it to the beginning.

Comment: Use `close(handles.figure1)` to close your GUI. And you can use `save()` and `load()` to reset the state. See an example [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/12/10/how-to-save-and-restore-state-of-a-gui-in-matlab/)